R Markdown file with chunks already evaluated, not sure where this is being stored
I have been working with a .Rmd file that now when I open it in RStudio, the chunks are already evaluated. I have not used the cache argument anywhere in the document, and am unsure where/how the evaluated chunks are being saved. There is no .RData file in the working directory that is being loaded upon starting the R session. Why are the chunks now evaluated upon launching RStudio, and how can I fix this so that they aren't evaluated until I run them?
(I apologize that I cannot provide a reprex due to the nature of this question; additionally, the .Rmd file I'm using is in a private repository.)

Have you tried to eliminate hidden folders?
-MacOs you press: Command + Shift + . (period).
-Windows: Ctrl + Shift + H

Thank you; I'm not sure if this is relevant but maybe I should have added to the question that I am using Ubuntu

That is likely just RStudio showing you the values they had last time they were evaluated in the IDE.  If you process the document, it will run them again, it won't use those saved values.  RStudio saves session information in the hidden .Rproj.user directory.
